# Add database and interface CRUD functions to class diagram

Tags: uml

I am creating a class diagram.

**Process**

1)Read Employee data from Active Directory

2) Add Employee detail to SQL Employee table

3) Read Details from XML file and update SQL table[image]
4) update the employee detail in active directory

I have created a class for employee , XML file  and a class for Linq to SQL crud functions and another class for the Linq to LDAP.

Question
I am not sure if i need to add all the crud operations and logging functions into the class diagram

Comment: The advise from @juhist is good. Talk with your team mates. You can create more than one diagram. One for overview (just relations) and other ones with details (about CRUD).

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to answer your question unless you provide more information. Do you have any specific design rules which tell what needs to be specified in the class diagram and what doesn't need to be specified in it? If there are no such rules, I would first consider adding the database layer functions to the class diagram and if the class diagram becomes too complicated then perhaps consider removing these.

This might be a good moment to have a discussion with the other team members what rules are used to make the class diagrams. What do you want to be in the diagrams and what can be omitted? If different persons have different opinions, then this conflict needs to be resolved somehow quickly because it's not a productive use of people's time to keep endlessly arguing what should be specified in a UML class diagram.